# How to prevent user copy files from OS X sandbox

Tags: macos, sandbox

I have some files which stored in OS x sandbox container. Which I need is prevent user to copy/drag&drop these files outside.

I had read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW6
about apple sandbox scheme. But have no help with me.
Could you help me? Thx.

Comment: Do you mind sharing you latest code?

Comment: The user has the ultimate control over their own computer. If they really want to, they can drag any file anywhere.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu There have no codes in my project. I just turn "Capability/App sandbox" on as apple dev said. For now could prevent user to open the target file in container.  But still can drop&drop the file.

Comment: @deceze Yeah... It seems like you said. I'm trying to find out a reliable way to resolve this requirement.

Comment: What is that requirement exactly? That your app holds some data which is absolutely 100% inaccessible to the user? That's not possible.